# How to get the invalid url in angular

Tags: angular

My working url is `localhost:4200/auth`, this is first route from `app.routing`.

If I entered something like this: `localhost:4200/something` this is a wrong url and it will redirect me to `localhost:4200/auth`, the initial route.

I want to  capture or get the wrong url that was entered. Is this possible?

I have seen many stackoverflow questions and answers. Many where how to redirect to a 404 page or how to get the previous url (I have tried this but I am not getting the invalid url instead I am getting `/auth` url https://dev.to/slk5611/how-to-access-the-previous-route-in-your-angular-app-5db0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to access your routes, set that every route without a known path should be redirected to a new route/page from your own:

Take a look at this [tutorial from GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-setup-404-page-in-angular-routing/).

Basically you create a new component and set it to be called:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: PostListComponent },
    { path: 'create', component: PostCreateComponent },
    { path: 'edit/:postId', 
        component: PostCreateComponent },
  
    //Wild Card Route for 404 request
    { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', 
        component: PagenotfoundComponent },
   // Code from GeeksForGeeks, reference above
];
```

Comment: So this is the same as what @KumaravelA meant by redirecting to a 404 page. If he was to go this route, you would need a service or some kind of way to extract the current url and use it that way.

Comment: if i entered a wrong url it  will take to 404 page right? but what i want is to get the wrong url path not redirect to 404 page

Comment: But when you type a url you need to reload the page. With this code, you are going to redirect only the view to that page, but you will still be able to get the route using the router service

Comment: Yes basically like what I said in my earlier comment, in your `pageNotFoundComponent` you'll need to use a service to get the current url which would be the `localhost:4200/something` url.

Answer (score 0):

To get the invalid url path ,

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      console.log("event")
    });
```